# Max Response Limitation im OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ

Tags: api, rest, sabre

I'm working with Sabre REST API. I have a issue with the OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ, I try limit the response number using the MaxResponses in the json structure but seems that I make something wrong because the response give to me 95 answers in the cert environment (https://api.cert.sabre.com/).
The json request that I use is:

```
{
"OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
    "Target": "Production",
    "PrimaryLangID": "ES",
    "MaxResponses": "15",
    "POS": {
        "Source": [{
            "RequestorID": {
                "Type": "1",
                "ID": "1",
                "CompanyName": {}
            }
        }]
    },
    "OriginDestinationInformation": [{
        "RPH": "1",
        "DepartureDateTime": "2016-04-01T11:00:00",
        "OriginLocation": {
            "LocationCode": "BOG"
        },
        "DestinationLocation": {
            "LocationCode": "CTG"
        },
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "SegmentType": {
                "Code": "O"
            }
        }
    }],
    "TravelPreferences": {
        "ValidInterlineTicket": true,
        "CabinPref": [{
            "Cabin": "Y",
            "PreferLevel": "Preferred"
        }],
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "TripType": {
                "Value": "Return"
            },
            "LongConnectTime": {
                "Min": 780,
                "Max": 1200,
                "Enable": true
            },
            "ExcludeCallDirectCarriers": {
                "Enabled": true
            }
        }
    },
    "TravelerInfoSummary": {
        "SeatsRequested": [1],
        "AirTravelerAvail": [{
            "PassengerTypeQuantity": [{
                "Code": "ADT",
                "Quantity": 1
            }]
        }]
    },
    "TPA_Extensions": {
        "IntelliSellTransaction": {
            "RequestType": {
                "Name": "10ITINS"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please make sure you are using correct endpoint. https://developer.sabre.com/docs/read/rest_basics/environments

Answer (score 2):

MaxResponses could be something for internal development which is part of the schema but does not affect the response.

What you can modify is in the IntelliSellTransaction. You used 10ITINS, but the values that will work should be **50ITINS, 100ITINS and 200ITINS**.

**EDIT2 (as Panagiotis Kanavos said):**
RequestType values depend on the business agreement between your company and Sabre. You can't use 100 or 200 without modifying the agreement.

```
"TPA_Extensions": {
    "IntelliSellTransaction": {
        "RequestType": {
            "Name": "50ITINS"
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT1:**
I have searched a bit more and found:

> OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ.TravelPreferences.TPA_Extensions.NumTrips
>
> Required: false
>
> Type: object
>
> Description: This element allows a user to specify the number of itineraries returned.

Comment: Thanx for your help, the first parameter (50ITINS) worked and set the limit to 50 results.
The second option didn't work, show me this answer:{
    "status": "NotProcessed",
    "type": "Validation",
    "errorCode": "ERR.2SG.CLIENT.INVALID_REQUEST",
    "timeStamp": "2016-02-05T07:44:37.073-06:00",
    "message": "Request is invalid: The request payload was malformed: Unexpected end-of-input within/between OBJECT entries  at [line: 147, column: 2086]"
}

Comment: Assuming there is no typo, the allowed RequestType values depend on the business agreement between your company and Sabre. You can't use `200ITINS` without a different contract. Besides, RequestType isn't a throttling mechanism. It's not supposed to *limit* the results, it specifies the type of results you want. There mey be results in the 200 results that you *do* want to display, eg, Business class results to display after the X cheapest Economy